# Get A Dictionary of Sums in a List group by ID

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a list  with a class Type TaxDetails

```
public class TaxDetails
{
   public string ID {get; set;}
   public string ItemID {get; set;}
   public string TaxID {get; set;}
   public string TaxCode {get; set;}
   public decimal TaxAmount {get; set;}
}
```

there can be many number of items with same Tax ID, but the ID does not repeat. I need to return a Dictionary which contains Tax id and it's sum. Which means when getting sum it should be group by the tax ID

```
Dictionary<string,decimal> taxSums
```

this dictionary contains only the tax id and its Total tax amount for that particular Taxid in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var result =
    list
    .GroupBy(x => x.TaxID) //Group by TaxID
     //Convert to dictionary. The key is the TaxID
     //and the value is the sum of tax amount values in the individual group
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(x => x.TaxAmount));
```

Comment: Thank You It Works

Comment: What about It groups by the TaxID as you have shown, and add the Tax code as the key of the Dictionary instead of the TaxID

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to mention it. it is another property in the class "TaxDetails" which I haven't mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Group then sum them.  Then throw the results in a dictionary.

```
var taxSums = context.TaxDetails.GroupBy(d => d.TaxID, d => d.TaxAmount)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum());
```